# slam_gmapping using imu data instead of /odom

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i am wondering whether we can use gmapping with imu data instead of /odom if yes what would be the pointer in this direction.

Thanks

(p.s i am using ubuntu 10.04 with ros electric)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47161/slam_gmapping-using-imu-data-instead-of-/odom/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-31**:
Please open individual threads for multiple questions keeping this one for the gmapping question.

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-10-31**:
@dornhege i edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simple answer is no. gmapping needs odometry.

You can either use SLAM that doesn't require this as [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) or find an intermediate node that can produce odometry from IMU or laser + imu. http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher should provide this functionality.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-10-31**:
@dornhege Thanks for answering are you aware of any implemented node which provide this conversion?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-31**:
see my edit.